# Visa-free transit in Korea

Tags: visas, transit, south-korea, jordanian-citizens

I'm flying from Auckland to China (layover) to Busan. Then 5 days in Korea, then Seoul to Japan. I am staying there for 3 months. I am from Jordan and a New Zealand permanent resident. I already have a Japan visitor visa. After 3 months I am going back to Auckland with Air China. Do I need to apply for a visitor visa for Korea or can I enter without a visa? On the HiKorea website they say you need to come to Korea on a direct flight.

Answer (score 2):

[This page says](https://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/OO/OO_EN_13_3_3.jsp):

> 1) Transit Tourists Travelling to a Third Country
>
> - You transit through Korea on your way to the United States (excluding Guam and Saipan), Japan, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand and hold a valid visa (including re-entry permit, but excluding e-visa or Japanese Group visa) issued by the aforementioned countries.

This is your case both ways, it seems, as long as the visa that you have for Japan is not an e-visa.